# How to use Pin tool in non JIT mode

Tags: c++, intel, instrumentation, intel-pin

I have written a Pintool and using it in JIT mode. I read from Pin tutorial that Pintool can be used in non JIT mode too but I cant understand how to do that. I need an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples in the Probes directory in the kit. Also look at replacesigprobed.cpp in the manual.

In general, a probe mode tool will use PIN_StartProgramProbed() and use only the APIs that are supported in probe mode.